# How to open n windows consuming the same long function at the same time

Tags: pysimplegui

I have a Python application that already works perfectly and contains about 3000 lines of code, so I'll be concise.

In my main code I have the following functions, here is an example:

```
def main():
 #contains settings and the data that goes to the function.

def function_thread(username, password):
#function that receives this data

def output();
#a window that displays the progress of the function.
```

This example:

'''

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from time import sleep
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def current_location(self):
    geometry = self.TKroot.geometry()
    location = geometry[geometry.find('+') + 1:].split('+')
    x, y = int(location[0]), int(location[1])
    
    return(x, y+-30)

sg.Window.current_location = current_location


def function_thread(usuario, senha):
    print(f'Tarefa {usuario} e {senha}')
    for i in range(5):
        print(f'Tarefas no perfil {usuario}')
        #sleep(2)
        #window.write_event_value('N', i)
    #window.write_event_value('Ok', usuario)
    #sleep(1)

x=-7
y=515
def abrir_abas():
    global x,y
    window2 = None    
    cont = 0
    list_user = [('perfil1','senha1'),('perfil2', 'senha2'),('perfil3', 'senha3'),('perfil4', 'senha4'),('perfil5','senha5'),('perfil6', 'senha6'),('perfil7', 'senha7'),('perfil8', 'senha8')]
    
    for i in list_user:
        titulo = 'TAB '+i[0]
        
        window2 = output(loc=(x,y)) 
        
        window2.TKroot.title(titulo)
        threading.Thread(target=function_thread(i[0],i[1]), daemon=True).start() 
       
        y=y+-30
        y=y 
        cont = cont + 1
        sleep(2)
             
             
def output(loc=(-7, 515))->sg.Window:
    
    voltar = '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'
    pause = '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'
         
    col_v = sg.Column(
            [
                [sg.Button(image_data=pause, size=(None,20), key='Executar',button_color=(sg.theme_background_color(), sg.theme_background_color()), border_width=0)],
                [sg.Text('')],
                [sg.Button(image_data=voltar, key='voltar',tooltip="Voltar",button_color=(sg.theme_background_color(), sg.theme_background_color()), border_width=0)],
            ], k='c_v', visible=True)
    main_layout =[
            #[sg.Titlebar(title = texto, key = 'titulo')],
            [sg.StatusBar('O Rei Dos BOTs',justification='center', font='Arial 12')],
            [col_v,sg.Output(size=(20,2),expand_x=True, expand_y=True, key='output')],
            [sg.StatusBar('INICIANDO', k='status+', auto_size_text=True, justification='center', font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), text_color='#FFFFFF', background_color=None, s=(None, 1))],
        ]

    window = sg.Window('ABA', size=(253,181),location=loc, background_color=None, auto_size_text=True, font='Arial 7', resizable=True, auto_size_buttons=False,right_click_menu = False, margins=(1, 1)).Layout(main_layout).Finalize()
    
    return window
        
        
def main_output():
    global window
    sg.theme('Topanga')
    layout = [  [sg.Text('Janela')],
                    [sg.Text(size=(10,1), key='-OUT-')],
                    [sg.Button('Executar'), sg.Button('Sair')],
                    [sg.StatusBar('INICIANDO', k='status', auto_size_text=True, justification='center', font='Arial 12', text_color='#FFFFFF', background_color=None, s=(None, 1))],
            ]

    window = sg.Window(' Title', layout, size=(253,181), use_default_focus=False,finalize=True, use_custom_titlebar=False, no_titlebar=False)
        
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event, values)
        
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Sair':
            break
        
        if event == 'Executar':
            window.hide()
            #with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            #    executor.map(abrir_abas())
            #threading.Thread(target=abrir_abas(), daemon=True).start() 
            abrir_abas()
            #threading.Thread(target=abrir_abas(), args=(window,), daemon=False).start()
                        
        if event == 'Ok':
            print('Completado')
                    
        if event == 'voltar':
            print('Voltar')

    window.close()

#threading.Thread(target=main_output(), args=(window,), daemon=True).start() 
main_output()
```

'''

I would like to open each output() window with a sleep(x) interval and display the execution of the function_thread(username, password) individually and that each output() window be independent of each other.

I use PySimplegui

Comment: Use PySimplegui to create my application's graphical interface.

EX:
I have a list of several users with a password. Each user opens a window (output()) user) some functions (function_th) and only one user can do this at a time.
I have when I run my application, open it, get the list of users and run in parallel with it through a loop

Comment: Jason Yang, I have a system I made to perform automated tasks by logging into a website, and today I use the system by opening and running 1 user account at a time.
I would like to copy my user list (ex: 100 users) and put it on my system and run them all at once

Comment: I added an example