# How do I open several windows in PySimpleGui, each window uses the same function and each window executes this function with a time interval

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

How do I open several windows in PySimpleGui, each window uses the same function and each window executes this function with a time interval.

The window has the same layout, it's just an output or multiline to show what the function is doing.

The function has a loop that lasts around 24 hours running, but it can run from 0 to 'x' hours.
I use Python and PySimpleGui

Comment: Code example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73155379/how-to-open-n-windows-consuming-the-same-long-function-at-the-same-time?noredirect=1#comment129204182_73155379

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it work all the time, didn't do more test, just for demo, popup windows not well placed when open.

Note: It won't return `WINDOW_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT` from `read_all_windows` when click `close` button of window if option `enable_close_attempted_event` of `Window` set to True. It maybe a bug for this moment.

```py
from time import sleep
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def function(win, username):
    global login
    while login[username][3]:
        sleep(1)
        win.write_event_value('ACK', username)
    win.write_event_value('Done', username)

def popup(username):
    sg.theme('DarkBlue4')
    layout = [[sg.ProgressBar(100, orientation='H', size=(20, 20), key='Progress')]]
    win = sg.Window(username, layout, finalize=True, enable_close_attempted_event=True)
    return win

users = {
    'Jason'  : '778877',
    'Michael': '123456',
    'William': 'aabbcc',
}

sg.theme('DarkBlue3')
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Username'), sg.Push(), sg.Input(do_not_clear=False, key='Username')],
    [sg.Text('Password'), sg.Push(), sg.Input(do_not_clear=False, key='Password')],
    [sg.StatusBar('', size=10, expand_x=True, key='Status')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Execute'), sg.Push()],
]
window = sg.Window('System', layout, finalize=True, enable_close_attempted_event=True)
status = window['Status']
login, windows, bye = {}, {}, False

while True:

    win, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
    print(repr(event))
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:  # sg.WINDOW_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT:
        sg.theme('DarkBlue5')
        if sg.popup_yes_no("Are you sure to close ?") == 'Yes':
            if win in windows:
                username = windows[win]
                login[username][3] = False
            else:
                if login:
                    bye = True
                    for username in login:
                        login[username][3] = False
                else:
                    break
    elif event == 'Execute':
        username, password = values['Username'], values['Password']
        if username not in users:
            status.update('Wrong username !')
        elif password != users[username]:
            status.update('Wrong password !')
        elif username in login:
            status.update('User executing !')
        else:
            w = popup(username)
            thread = threading.Thread(target=function, args=(w, username), daemon=True)
            login[username] = [w, thread, 0, True]
            windows[w] = username
            thread.start()

    elif event == 'ACK':
        username = values[event]
        login[username][2] = count = (login[username][2] + 10) % 101
        win['Progress'].update(count)

    elif event == 'Done':
        username = values[event]
        win.close()
        del login[username]
        del windows[win]
        if not login and bye:
            break

for win in windows:
    win.close()
window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jason Yang!
I will adapt your example to my code!
I returned with the result.